# not support macro excel 2003

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem I can not solve this code works fine in excel 2007 but in 2003 they can not adapt it please help me?

```
   Set h1 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    wpath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    u = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1").Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G2:G" & u), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange Range("A1:P" & u)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Worksheet.Sort` property does not exist in Excel 2003 because the feature was added later.
There is nothing to replace it with. Your code simply does not support Excel 2003.

Comment: +1, and to clarify, in 2003 you were not able to sort an entire worksheet, but could sort on a range. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213557(v=office.11).aspx)